# Building a deck of cards in java using 2 different ENUMS

Tags: java, enums

I have a lab for class (we are allowed to seek outside help) creating klondike solitaire. I am a total noob when it comes to programming (this is my first ever class in programming). We just learned about enums, and I have to build a deck using them (I've reviewed other questions about this, but I haven't found a solution that matches what I need yet). We have two enums (rank and suit):

```
public enum Rank {
ACE,
TWO,
THREE,
FOUR,
FIVE,
SIX,
SEVEN,
EIGHT,
NINE,
TEN,
JACK,
QUEEN,
KING;}
```

and

```
public enum Suit {    
CLUBS,
SPADES,
HEARTS,
DIAMONDS;}
```

Now, I need to combine them into an array called Deck, which stands as such:

```
public Deck() {
    cards = new Card[52];
}
```

To put the cards into the deck, I've been trying to use the ".values" but I can't get it right. There is a testing code with this lab and it says I'm not getting any of the points for this. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public void fill() {
        for (int i = 0; i<52;i++){
        for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
        for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
            cards[i]= new Card(r,s);
   }
   }
   }
   }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your inner loops create every suit for every rank. This is every card, you don't need to do this 52 times because it is just going to do the same thing.. What you do want is to put a different card in each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state,

> Now, I need to combine them into an array called Deck, which stands as such:

No, you need to create a class Card that has one field of each of the enums. Only after doing that can you create a Deck of your Cards. So do that -- create a Card class, give it at least two fields, one for each enum, plus an appropriate constructor, plus getters, plus a decent `toString()` and then you're set.

Also, this is wrong:

```
public void fill() {
    for (int i = 0; i<52;i++){ // get rid of this loop
    for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
    for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
        cards[i]= new Card(r,s);
}
```

The code above will try to stuff 52 cards into each index spot. For instance, it will try to stuff all 52 cards into the cards[0] spot, same for the cards[1] item, and only the last Card will be added. You'll have an array of 52 King of Diamonds -- not what you want.

Instead, get rid of the outer loop, and instead increment the i inside your loop:

```
public void fill() {
  int i = 0;
  for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
    for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
      cards[i]= new Card(r,s);
      i++;  // increment i here
    }
  }
}
```