# How do i generate a deck of cards in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have tried again and again but the loop is stuck at the king of clubs.
currently I am trying to generate a deck of cards and print it out to check if the deck is actual

```
      import java.util.*;
      import java.math.*;
 public class Deck extends Card{

private static Card[][]cardDeck=new Card[4][13];
int counter; 



public Deck (String suit, String cardType, int value) 
{
    super(suit,cardType,value);

}

public void removeCard() 
{
    if(counter>=40)
        generateDeck();

    int Randr=(int)(Math.random()*26);
    int Randc=(int)(Math.random()*2);

    if(cardDeck[Randr][Randc]==null)
    {
        removeCard();
    }
    else
        {
        cardDeck[Randr][Randc]=null;
        counter++;
        }
}
public void print2DArray() 
{
    for(int i=0;i<cardDeck.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<cardDeck[0].length;j++)
        {                   
            System.out.print(super.draw(cardDeck[i][j])+" "+j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}



public static void generateDeck()
{

    for(int i=0; i<cardDeck.length;i++) {

        for(int j=0;j<cardDeck[0].length;j++) {

            if(i==0)
            {
                if(j==0)
                {
                    cardDeck[0][0]=new Card("Clubs","Ace",1);
                    continue;
                }
                else if(j>0&&j<10)
                {
                        cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Clubs",""+(j+1),j+1);
                        continue;
                }
                else if(j==10)
                {
                        cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Clubs","Jack",10);
                        continue;
                }
                else if(j==11)
                {
                        cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Clubs","Queen",10);
                        continue;
                }
                else if(j==12)
                {
                        cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Clubs","King",10);
                        continue;
                }
            else if(i==1)
            {
                if(j==0)
                {
                    cardDeck[1][0]=new Card("Hearts","Ace",1);
                    continue;
                }
                else if(j>0&&j<10)
                {
                        cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Hearts",""+(j+1),j+1);
                        continue;
                }
                else if(j==10)
                {
                        cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Hearts","Jack",10);
                        continue;
                }
                else if(j==11)
                {
                        cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Hearts","Queen",10);
                        continue;
                }
                else if(j==12)
                {
                        cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Hearts","King",10);
                        continue;
                }
            }
            else if(i==2)
            {
                if(j==0)
                {
                    cardDeck[2][0]=new Card("Spades","Ace",1);
                    continue;
                }
                else if(j>0&&j<10)
                {
                    cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Spades",""+(j+1),j+1);
                    continue;
                }
                else if(j==10)
                {
                    cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Spades","Jack",10);
                    continue;
                }
                else if(j==11)
                {   
                    cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Spades","Queen",10);
                continue;
                }
                else if(j==12)
                {
                    cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Spades","King",10);
                continue;
                }
            }
            else if(i==3)
            {
                if(j==0)
                {
                    cardDeck[3][0]=new Card("Diamonds","Ace",1);
                    continue;
                }
                else if(j>0&&j<10)
                {
                    cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Diamonds",""+(j+1),j+1);
                    continue;
                }
                else if(j==10)
                {   
                    cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Diamonds","Jack",10);
                    continue;
                }
                else if(j==11)
                {
                    cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Diamonds","Queen",10);
                    continue;
                }

                else if(j==12)
                {
                    cardDeck[i][j]=new Card("Diamonds","King",10);
                    continue;
                }

               }    
            }
        }
                }
}
```

}

my card class is just a basic class with a few get methods

```
public class Card {


private static String suit;
private static int numVal;
private static String cardType;

public Card(String s,String cT, int val) {
    suit=s;
    numVal=val;
    cardType=cT;
}
public String draw(Card card) {

    return "Your card is "+card.getSuit()+" "+card.getCardType()+" its value is "+card.getValue();
}

public static String getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}
public static String getCardType()
{
    return cardType;
}
public static int getValue()
{
    return numVal;
}
```

}

my main method is just to check if it will print

```
public class TestEnvironment {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deck x= new Deck("","",0);
    x.generateDeck();
    x.print2DArray();
}
```

}

heres my updated code for the if else statements aforementioned

```
import java.util.*;
```

import java.math.*;
public class Deck extends Card{

```
private static Card[][]cardDeck=new Card[4][13];
int counter;
public Deck (String suit, String cardType, int value) 
{
    super(suit,cardType,value);

}

public void removeCard() 
{
    if(counter>=40)
        generateDeck();

    int Randr=(int)(Math.random()*26);
    int Randc=(int)(Math.random()*2);

    if(cardDeck[Randr][Randc]==null)
    {
        removeCard();
    }
    else
        {
        cardDeck[Randr][Randc]=null;
        counter++;
        }
}
public void print2DArray() 
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<cardDeck[0].length;j++)
        {   
            System.out.print(i);
            //System.out.println(super.draw(cardDeck[i][j])+"     "+i+","+j);
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}



public static void generateDeck()
{   int value=0;
    String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    String[] ranks = {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"};

    for (int i=0;i<suits.length;i++) 

        for (int j=0;j<ranks.length;j++) 
        {   
            cardDeck[i][j] = new Card(suits[i],ranks[j],value);
            if(j>9)
            value =10;
            else
            value=j+1;

            cardDeck[i][j] = new Card(suits[i],ranks[j],value);        
        }
```

Comment: When the system asks you to improve your question ... because it thinks you might have to much code and not enough text, adding such useless "garbage characters" ... will only annoy your readers. Get you downvotes, close votes, delete votes. You better quickly delete those, and read [mcve] to improve your question.

Comment: Dovnvote for qwrwqtwqrtewyqtfqwterwqtyerqytreqytwreqytwerqyteryqtreyqtwerqytweryqtreywqtreyqtwerwyqterqyterq  - ---- - I hope that this is a good reason.

Comment: `public class Deck extends Card{`. A Deck is not a Card. A Deck consists of cards, but it is not a Card.

Comment: Beyond that answer you already got: you should be using enums here, not strings. Create one enum for the suites, and one for the card type. And then you reduce your code to ... well, much less: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329132/building-a-deck-of-cards-in-java-using-2-different-enums

Comment: When you post code make sure you select all the code and then click the `{}` button. The code will then be indented 4 spaces and will be highlighted properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use a 2D Array. Instead use an ArrayList to hold the cards.
2. Then you create two loops to add the cards to the ArrayList. The outer loop will iterate through the 4 suits and the inner loop will add the 13 cards for each suit.
3. Then you can use `Collections.shuffle()` to shuffle the Cards in the ArrayList.
4. To play a card you just remove card 0 from the ArrayList.

Edit:

> but the loop is stuck at the king of clubs.

Well your `generateCards()` method uses too many if/else statements to generate the cards. It is hard to notice which if/else statement might be causing the problem.

You can simplify the code by using arrays and loops.

Something like:

```
String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", ... , "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

for (each suit) // assume i is the index
    for (each rank) // assume j is the index
    {
        int value = (j < 10) ? 10 : j;
        cardDeck[i][j] = new Card(...);        
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

> it is stuck at the spades of kings

I'm guessing the following is your problem:

```
private static String suit;
private static int numVal;
private static String cardType;
```

Don't use static variables. The Static keyword means that all instances of the Card class will share the same value.

Comment: this is for a class and my teacher wanted us to use a 2d array for the deck of cards

Comment: @Sai, Whenever you have so many nested if/else statements you need to look for a better way to write the code and make the code cleaner. See edit for one approach.

Comment: I tried the code but now it is stuck at the spades of kings.

Comment: And hint: when giving all these hints ... also mention the core thing: to not use raw types, but to use enums. One for suites, one for card types. The key thing to reduce the awful unnecessary complexity in the code base is to use better abstractions.

Comment: @Sai, `it is stuck at the spades of kings` - not sure what that means. The king of spades would be the last card you create, so I would say your code is finished. In any case you still haven't deleted all the garbage characters in your question and you haven't updated the code to post a proper [mcve] showing your current code so I can't offer any more help.

Comment: @GhostCat, this is a simple school exercise. The OP needs to learn to walk before they run. There is no need to introduce more complex concepts for a simple exercise like this. The question you referred to in your comment was for a school exercise specifically designed to use enums.

Comment: @camickr I tried the code and tried to printed it but, the code fallsthrough and only prints the king of spades.                                                    Your card is Spades King its value is 12     0,0
Your card is Spades King its value is 12     0,1
etc.

Comment: `only prints the king of spades` - did you see edit 2?