# How to create a deck of cards in Java

Tags: java, arrays

*Edit I am unable to use the java collection classes in this project.

I have created my card class and now I need to figure out how to create a deck of cards in my deck class. I am a beginner so sorry if this seems like a very stupid question.

**Card Class**

```
Public class Card {
    private final String rank;
    private final String suit;

    public Card(String rank, String suit){
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public String getRank(){
        return rank;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return (this.rank + " of " + this.suit);
    }
}
```

**Deck**

```
String suit[] = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
String rank[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "King", "Queen", "Ace"};


public void DeckOfCards() {


}
```

Comment: Your `Card` class will not compile. `Public` and `public` are not same things as Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: You create a nested loop. for each suit and then for each rank you create an instance of your Card and then you add the card to an ArrayList. The ArrayList becomes your card deck.

Comment: It's better to read about and use [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to represent [card ranks and suits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329132/building-a-deck-of-cards-in-java-using-2-different-enums).

Comment: I don't know how you plan on using this but many games use a a single character for both rand and suit.  So the king of hearts would be KH.  And T is used in place of a ten.

Answer (score 1):

Extrapolating from your work, the deck of cards can be represented as an array of 52 Card objects:

```
String suit[] = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
String rank[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "King", "Queen", "Ace"};
Card[] deck = new Card[52];
//Assigning values to each card in the deck
int ctr = 0;
for (int i = 0; ctr < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; ++j) {
        deck[ctr] = new Card(rank[j], suit[i]);
        ++ctr;
    }
}
```

In which the variable deck is the desired deck of cards.